# Keeping big requests in redux state

Tags: redux, immutable.js

I use `immutable.js` to keep my application state. It's made of multiple combined reducers, that are immutable maps like:

```
const initialState = new Map({
   data: null,
   page: 1,
   ...
});
```

So I have a request response I need to fetch, save somewhere, get data from, and update the state, whenever something on the webpage changes.

The question is - **where do I keep raw request responses in redux?**

Let's say, I want to keep it inside the state. I tried the following approaches:

```
case FETCH_RESPONSE:
    return state.merge({
        rawRequestResponse: action.response // very slow, deep conversion to Immutable
    })
case FETCH_RESPONSE:
    return state.set({
        rawRequestResponse: action.response // also slow, it's converted to Immutable, though not deeply
    })
case FETCH_RESPONSE:
    return new Map({
        rawRequestResponse: action.response, // just like above
        ...
    })
```

But they all are too slow. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Is the raw request truly a needed part of your state? Reconsider if it really needs to live inside the redux store. How large is it anyway? If you’re dealing with huge collections, then consider adding pagination to the API and caching collection entities on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about passing a plain object to `set()`, but if you pass the key as a string, then the value as the second argument, nothing should be converted:

```
return state.set('rawRequestResponse', action.response)
```